# Is there an heredoc feature for windows batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

In linux, you can send a block of text easily with wrapping the block in braces. For example,
    {
       a
       block
       of
       text
    }
Is there any way to do this easily in windows? I know it might work by using the \ on everyline, but that seems like such a hassle.

Edit: I've gotten it to work using ^. Thanks

Comment: are you looking for \n?

Comment: Know I just want to send a block (multiple lines) of text to another file.

Comment: What's wrong with \ on every line? That's how multi-line `echo` statements work in Windows...

Comment: Like I said, it seems a hassle especially when you have more than ten lines. I was just wonder if there was something better I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly as hell, like all Windows command line script, but you can use `^` as the line "escape" char:

```
C:\Users\marc>echo foo ^
More? bar ^
More? baz ^
More? hello world > con
foo bar baz hello world
```

Note the `> con` at the end. If you don't put it, you end just getting `More?` until you hit enter twice, or enter an `n`, and those empty lines become part of the output.

```
C:\Users\marc>echo foo ^
More? bar ^
More? baz ^
More?
More?
foo bar baz


C:\Users\marc>
```

Comment: Yes I stubmled upon this option as well. Why doesn't batch just have a simple solution like linux?

Comment: because cmd.exe dates to when M$ though no one would EVER need to use a command line ever again, because you could do everything in the GUI, and things you couldn't do in the GUI didn't exist because the GUI could do everything. Why bother adding all kinds of features to a tool that no one would need to use?

Comment: That's interesting, I guess they didn't want to update it either. Thanks for help. I guess I'll just have use the cirumflex then.